# Neo4j - cant import with neo4j-import

Tags: csv, neo4j, illegalargumentexception

Helo, I get an error while trying to import the tutorial from here:
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/04/spark-generating-csv-files-to-import-into-neo4j.html , my only change is I need to use it with ; as delimeter

I want to use ; as a delimeter. It has to be done through this neo4j import method and not using LOAD CSV with Cypher, so this the only method, and I dont know why it is not working

first two lines crimes.csv
id:ID(Crime);:LABEL;date;description;caseNumber;arrest:Boolean;domestic:Boolean;fbiCode
10465449;Crime;03/28/2016 11:52:00 PM;POSSESSION OF DRUG EQUIPMENT;HZ204933;true;false;18

[image: illegalArgumentException]

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using `arrest:boolean` instead of `arrest:Boolean`? And why can't you use ";" as a delimiter with LOAD CSV? The example in the Neo4j manual uses it:

`LOAD CSV FROM 'http://neo4j.com/docs/2.3.3/csv/artists-fieldterminator.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR
  ';'
CREATE (:Artist { name: line[1], year: toInt(line[2])})`

Comment: I would also try something like `LOAD CSV FROM ... as line FIELDTERMINATOR ';' WITH line LIMIT 1 RETURN line` to look at your file in the excellent neeo4j browser tool

Answer (score 1):

1. The import tool's default array delimiter is the semicolon (";"). So, if you want to use ";" as the field delimiter, you also need to change the array delimiter.
2. You should quote the delimiter characters on the command line, to to avoid possible issues.

Try using something like this to specify the delimiters on the command line (assuming "|" is not used in your CSV files):

```
--delimiter ";" --array-delimiter "|"
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the responses

problem was I used "delimeter" instead of "delimiter"
changing it to delimiter fixed my problem